# Filtering coverage with Lombok, Gradle, Jacoco and Sonar

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, lombok

I'm using Gradle 4.4 on my Java project with JaCoCo 0.8.0, and Sonar with SonarJava 5.0.1.

I have a class annotated with lombok's `@Value` and `@Builder`.

My JaCoCo config in build.gradle looks like this:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.0"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
}

jacocoTestReport.doFirst{
    classDirectories = files("buildDir/classes")
}

task jacocoReport(type: JacocoReport){
    sourceSets sourceSets.main
    executionData test, integrationTest
}
```

Also, I have lombok.confi file, with property `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true`, and generated stuff does actually have `@lombok.Generated` annotation in build/classes.

However, the coverage on Sonar is still low. It reports a ton of conditions and lines to cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [announcement of release of JaCoCo version 0.8.0](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/e2PVMeMvA8k/uHsJbi4iAQAJ):

> Please Note
>
> Tools that directly read exec files (which is not a final report) and embed JaCoCo for generation of report will provide filtering functionality only after they updated to this version of JaCoCo.
>
> So please follow/wait/etc respective vendors such as
>   **SonarQube** - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2608
>
> Reports generated by corresponding version (0.8.0) of integrations developed as part of JaCoCo project by us (Ant Tasks, Maven Plugin and Command Line Interface) provide filtering functionality.
>
> With Gradle JaCoCo Plugin you can select both runtime and version for "JaCoCoReport" task using "toolVersion" - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

This is also stated in [JaCoCo changelog](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html):

> Note: Tools that directly read exec files and embed JaCoCo for this (such as **SonarQube** or Jenkins) will provide filtering functionality only after they updated to this version of JaCoCo.

As of today (29 Jan 2018) fix for https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2608 is supposed to be in not yet released SonarJava plugin version 5.1.

From all the above: report generated by Gradle should already be filtered, report generated by SonarQube will be filtered after upgrade of SonarJava.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from configuring lombok, I also had to tell sonar scanner where to find the dependencies. Was the only way to get rid of the "Unused private fields should be removed" message in SonarQube.

I followed instructions from this site: https://netwolfuk.wordpress.com/2017/10/29/maven-sonarqube-jacoco-lombok-and-teamcity/

It boils down to:

1. Tell maven to copy its dependencies to somewhere Sonar can find them. This is simple as adding:

   ```
   dependency:copy-dependencies
   ```
2. Add the following to the sonar build step:

   ```
   -Dsonar.java.libraries=target/dependency/*.jar
   ```